# What are the consquences of having Configured OS setting wrong

Tags: vmware

We are running VMware 6.

What are the consequences of having Configured OS being different from Running OS? In our rig I see several VMs where configured vs running is e.g. like this:

```
Other (32-bit),     Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)
Other (32-bit),     Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 (64-bit),    Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit),    Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (64-bit),    Other 2.6.x Linux (64-bit)
```

We have come to the conclusion that it "doesn't seem to be a problem", and since it requires a restart that is hard to get permission to do, we'll leave it as it is.

But I would like to know what exactly this configuration does, and what we loose by not correcting this (or what we can gain by doing so).

PS: I'm not really working with the VMware side of things, but gets involved, I'm provisioning and maintaining the Linux VMs on it.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you are doing with those VMs.  Obviously, a 32-bit Linux VM won't be able to run 64-bit programs, though the reverse might be true.

Comment: All our servers have 64-bit versions of the OS installed. RHEL7 or RHEL6 (or even a few RHEL5 for a while). So I guess one of the things interesting to know about is what the consequence of running e.g. RHEL7 (64-bit), but having the configuration in VMware set to "Other (32-bit)". I can't see that this prevents 64-bit programs for running, but what is different?

Comment: I may be wrong, but in principle I don't see how a 64 bit OS could run on a 32 bit machine.  Again, I may be wrong.

Comment: I'm quite sure it doesn't. But that is not relevant to the question. The "Configured OS" setting in VMware is obviously wrong, and I was hoping someone could tell me what the consequence is, if any.